# Защита платного приложения Android

Tags: android, java

Всем Добрый День!

Сейчас думаю о защите платного приложения. У меня будет одна версия приложения. Сначала пользователь бесплатно устанавливает приложение. Но в самом приложении сделать функцию покупки приложения-ключа для про-версии. В самом приложении будет проверка если хеши данного приложения-ключа совпадают с реальными - то включать про версию приложения.

Чтобы исключить использование freedom (подменяет google play) при покупке pro-ключа. Я сделаю проверку на своём сервере с google wallet, было ли оплачено приложение. Также это исключит покупку и возврат средств.

Всё ли я учёл, можно ли как-то ещё взломать? Посоветуйте свои способы защиты. И да ещё, можно ли как-то запутать саму проверку этого приложения-ключа, чтобы человек не мог из ассемблировского кода вырезать это условие.

Comment: Можно поставить проверку на старте приложения. Допустим каждый день или неделю при запуске приложения будет запускаться сервис, который будет проверять взломанное или нет приложение. Ну и от реверс инжиниринга поможет обфускация. Если приложение не вообще прям супер крутое, то никто не будет заморачиваться с его взломом.

Comment: @Deadkenny, проверка на взлом именно такая, которую я описал? Было ли оплачено приложение?

Comment: я вас огорчу, что не всегда можно получить hash ключа. возможно вы никогда не столкнетесь с такими устройствами, но поверьте, они есть.

Comment: @iproger Не знаю что обозначает "хеш приложения-ключа". Но у пользователя может быть несколько устройств, привязанных к одному гугло-аккаунту. И ему было бы неприятно выяснить, что про надо покупать для каждого устройства.

Comment: Он просто скинет файл-ключ себе на другое устройство. А по его аккаунту будет проверятся купил ли аккаунт это приложение или нет. Таким образом сделали Titanium Backup

Comment: Я бы немного по другому делал. Хранил бы на сервере в базе хэши тех, кто купил, а хэш генерировал для пользователя при покупке на основе его учетки(на основе каких данных генерировать сами придумайте). Ну и соответственно обыкновенным запросом возвращал бы JSON с результатом. Тогда пользователь на другом устройстве мог бы нажать кнопку "Восстановить покупку" и если он есть в базе, то покупка восстановится. Ну и проверку от взлома делать с определенным интервалом. Запрашивать инфу о покупке для про клиентов раз в определенное время и если приложение взломано - блокировать фичи.

Comment: @Deadkenny, спасибо! Возможно так и сделаю. А там как можно сделать, чтобы гугл отправлял мне на сервер инфу о том что такой-то пользователь купил приложение?

Comment: Можно использовать AccountManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html
для получения имени аккаунта. Или заставить пользователя придумать секретное слово. И еще неплохо было бы делать запрос ответ к серверу с какой-нибудь хэш сверткой типа вопрос-ответ. Чтобы нельзя было подделать ответ сервера.

Answer (score 2):

Самая лучшая защита любого приложения - это лицензионное соглашение.

Напишите приложение, которое большинству захочется приобрести, нежели поломать.

Comment: Поддерживаю, при качественной работе большинство пиратов становятся клиентами.

Comment: Напишите приложение, которое большинству захочется приобрести, нежели поломать.

Типичная фраза типичных пиратов. С ними надо не договоравитаться, а наказывать, шрафовать, а лучше сажать. И мне пофигна минусы

Comment: @danpetruk так пишете, как будто ничего не пиратили в жизни.

Comment: @Deadkenny быстро бросил, когда узнал, что к чему

Comment: @danpetruk, а про идею, что информация (и софт тоже) *должна быть свободной* никогда не слышали?

Comment: @avp, да, ещё и про коммунизм слышал.. Что-то меня не прёт от этих двух идей...

Comment: При этом первой из них (опосредовано и вполне вероятно, неосознанно) пользуетесь постоянно, например, в том же Android.

Comment: @avp, да, но в отличии от типичных опен-сорс проектов, android разрабатывает не community, а коммерческая компания. И, в отличии от опен сорс проектов, в лицензии есть строчка, обязывающая сохранить сервисы гугла в форках. На чём они деньги и делают

Comment: @danpetruk, вообще-то я имел в виду главным образом ядро, на котором развернут Android (ну, и кучу библиотек, которыми все с удовольствием пользуются).

Answer (score -2):

Да, всё идеально. Правда ещё стоило бы [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) -om обработать.

Как могут взломать? Могут попробовать вмешаться в общение приложения с вашим сервером. Или очень долгий и нудный реверс инжиниринг, но если у переложения меньше 500 000 юзеров, вряд ли кто-либо будет этим заниматься.

Я бы ещё добавил полную блокировку приложения, если на телефе установлен freedom. Но это на ваше усмотрение

Comment: А вот за такие проделки с чужим имуществом и "заехать" недолго.